# CMS pages structure in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, architecture, content-management-system

I'm trying to create CMS with MEAN stack. And I have a conceptional problem on very first fundamentals.

What is the best way to store page tree structure(parent pages and child pages) in MongoDB? I've read docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-parent-references/ but that way force me to search the DB recursively(so I need to forget about async). Is it the best way? Maybe I need to store pages ID in one of configuration files? Or maybe MongoDB isn't good for that kind of app?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/ is your friend. Materialized paths should do it for you, really.